# Writable Nested Serializer Django Rest Framework with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, django, django-forms, django-rest-framework, multipartform-data

I am trying to use [Writable Nested Serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) with AngularJS. I have image field in the related model. So its something like this:

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('order', 'title', 'duration', 'thumbnail')  # ImageField here

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tracks_data = validated_data.pop('tracks')
        album = Album.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for track_data in tracks_data:
            Track.objects.create(album=album, **track_data)
        return album
```

Now I want to post the data in the docs its mentioned like this -

```
>>> data = {
    'album_name': 'The Grey Album',
    'artist': 'Danger Mouse',
    'tracks': [
        {'order': 1, 'title': 'Public Service Announcement', 'duration': 245},
        {'order': 2, 'title': 'What More Can I Say', 'duration': 264},
        {'order': 3, 'title': 'Encore', 'duration': 159},
    ],
}
>>> serializer = AlbumSerializer(data=data)
>>> serializer.is_valid()
True
>>> serializer.save()
<Album: Album object>
```

How to achieve same using AngularJS. I am trying to do the same using FormData in AngularJS. But its returning the nested object as unicode instead of list.

How to post data using AngularJS forms with imagefield in Nested model. I am even not able to replicate the above case because the Angular is returning like this in request.data -

```
{
    'album_name': 'The Grey Album',
    'artist': 'Danger Mouse',
    'tracks': "[
        {'order': 1, 'title': 'Public Service Announcement', 'duration': 245},
        {'order': 2, 'title': 'What More Can I Say', 'duration': 264},
        {'order': 3, 'title': 'Encore', 'duration': 159},
    ]",  # note that list here is unicode instead of list
}
```

How should this be done ?

Edit:

```
angular
.module('myapp')
.factory('submissionsSvc',function($http,$q){
    return{
        addAlbumTrack : function(){
            $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/url',
                    data    : data,  
                    headers : { 'Content-Type': undefined },
                  }).
                    success(function(data, status, headers,config){
                      //deferred.resolve(data);
                    }).
                    error(function(data, status, headers,config){
                      //deferred.reject(status);
                    });
                }
            }
            }
```

Form Data

```
$scope.submitAlbumTracks = function(){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("album_name", $scope.albumTrack.album_name);
    fd.append("artist", $scope.albumTrack.artist);
    fd.append("tracks", $scope.albumTrack.tracks);
    submissionsSvc.addAlbumTrack(fd).then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

UPDATE:
It seems [this](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/103) is relevant . Any solution to this ?

Comment: unicode? it's a json decode it to get the list

Comment: i am talking about the tracks list. I want to pass it to serializer, but it will not accept data of this type

Comment: show your angularjs http request, and how you build the object given to the rest-framework